# Is there a way to get to a data store located behind a server?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

In Deus Ex: Human Revolution, I hack just about anything I come across. More than once, I've come across a situation where a data store was located behind the server, as can be seen in the following screenshot:

[image: Sneaky little store]

Since capturing the server successfully terminates the hacking attempt, I have never been able to get to such data stores. I'd attribute this to some randomization mishap when the hacking minigame is generated, but my impression is that there is a finite set of hacking minigame templates (as I've come across specific layouts more than once). If so, it would make no sense to create layouts with unreachable data stores (from a gameplay perspective).

Am I looking too much into this, or is there some sort of trick to getting these data stores?

Comment: I remember this situation too, it was quite confusing, not to mention annoying!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can't *directly* capture it, but you **can** get credit for it.

When you capture all of the diagnostic subroutines in a system, you automatically get access to all the data stores and the hacking mini-game ends. So in the example in the screenshot you posted, if you were to capture the diagnostic subroutine node (the red one), the hacking attempt would end in success, but you would automatically receive whatever bonus was contained in the data store beyond that subroutine (and all the others, too). In some puzzles, going for the diagnostic subroutine(s) is easier than going for the I/O node.

Throughout my play, where my OCD tendencies compelled me to hack every single hackable thing I found, I never ran into a single system where you couldn't get all of the data stores either by traditional means or by hacking the diagnostic subroutines.

Comment: +1 - I had no idea that hacking the red node gives you everything. I used to work so hard to capture everything *else* and *then* the red node...

Comment: I would never have guessed... thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Hacking the subroutine grants you access to the datastore so you don't have to hack it directly. The dotted arrow signifies that access is one way only therefore once you've hacked the diagnostic subroutine node you unlock whatever's stored on the datastore automatically. I just figured this out myself in TYM with one of the alarm panels in the lower section.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! This answer repeats an existing answer. Use your votes and comments to respond to those answers before making your own.